# i want to show id in text box with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

View page :

```
<label >Challan No.</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dispach_challan_no"  name="dispach_challan_no" placeholder="Enter Challan No">

 <script>
    $.ajax({
            url :"<?php echo base_url();>booking/dispatch_challan/DispatchChallanController/fetchId",
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){

              $('#dispach_challan_no').html(data);

            },
            error:function(data){
              alert("error message"+data);
            },async:false,
          });    
  </script>
```

Modle page:

```
  public function fetchId(){
                 $query= $this->db->select('*')->from('bilty')->get();                  
                return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller

```
public function fetchId()
{
 $modelResult = $this->dispatchModel->fetchId();
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Not getting where actually are you stuck?

Comment: `$('#dispach_challan_no').val(data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this --

**View Page -**

```
<label >Challan No.</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dispach_challan_no"  name="dispach_challan_no" placeholder="Enter Challan No">

 <script>
    $.ajax({
            url :"<?php echo base_url();>booking/dispatch_challan/DispatchChallanController/fetchId",
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data){

              $('#dispach_challan_no').val(data[0]['id']);

            },
            error:function(data){
              alert("error message"+data);
            },async:false,
          });    
  </script>
```

**Model --**

```
    public function fetchId(){
                 $query= $this->db->select('*')->from('bilty')->get();                  
                return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Controller --**

```
public function fetchId()
{
 $modelResult = $this->dispatchModel->fetchId();
 echo json_encode($modelResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply fetch ID from your response.

try like this

```
 success: function(data){
       var result =  data;
          $('#dispach_challan_no').html(result.id);

        },
```

or

```
   success: function(data){
           var result =  data;
              $('#dispach_challan_no').html(result['id']);

            },
```